# Is it possible to cut down or add up an initialized array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Initially i just initialize an array like

`Integer[] array = new Integer[10];`

and iam using this array in a `adapter` , so if we re-initialize using `new` the adapter need to be recreated.

Is there any way to allocate additional memory to the created array? as well as to cut down object?

**eg:**

if i have 5 more elements can i extend the array to a size of 15 ?

**Note:** Using `Collections` like `ArrayList` or `Vectors` is a way but its operations require complex management for my use. So is there any array operation to do the above work?

Comment: What is complex management ?

Comment: i have tens of such array , some can be hardcoded in the begining like  Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5}; and there is no add or remove calls for these arrays. So if i alter the implementation , i must reimplement the whole. thats why